# How to optimize the code snippet which has several calls to find method that is to read files and load them into the map?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a functionality to read files and load them into the map `m_fileParams`.

Then I am searching the specific keys in the map container using `find`. Here using `find` I am searching different keys.

My code is working fine. But I wanted to know how best I can optimize the code?

In several places I have used `find` to search the key in the map. Is there any way I can write generic method?

`m_fileParams` is declared in a header file:

```
std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> m_fileParams;
```

Here is the `ReadFile` function, which resides in a .cpp file:

```
bool McEMRMgr::ReadFile()
{
    IOperation* pFileReader = new McFileReader();
    std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> mapFileReaderResponse;
    if(pFileReader)
    {
        std::wstring strVendor, wstrFileLocation, wstrRegLocation;
        std::wstring FileType, regType;

        auto manufacSearchValue = m_fileParams.find(VENDOR);
        if (manufacSearchValue != m_fileParams.end())
        {
            strVendor.assign(manufacSearchValue->second);
            transform(
                strVendor.begin(), strVendor.end(),
                strVendor.begin(),
                towlower);

        }
        else
        {
            strVendor.assign(L"default");
            FileType.assign(L".File");
            regType.assign(L".registry");
        }
        auto emailSearchValue = m_fileParams.find(L"email_locations." + strVendor + L".type" + FileType);
        if (emailSearchValue != m_fileParams.end())
        { 
            if (emailSearchValue->second.compare(L"File") == 0)
            {
                auto FileSearchPath = m_fileParams.find(L"email_locations." + strVendor + L".paths" + FileType);
                wstrFileLocation = FileSearchPath->second;
            }
        }

        { 
            emailSearchValue = m_fileParams.find(L"email_locations." + strVendor + L".type" + regType);
            if (emailSearchValue->second.compare(L"registry") == 0)
            {
                auto regSearchPath = m_fileParams.find(L"email_locations." + strVendor + L".paths" + regType);
                wstrRegLocation = regSearchPath->second;
            }
        }
        if (wstrFileLocation.length() != 0)
        {
            std::wstring oemFolderPath;
            auto oemSearchType = m_fileParams.find(L"oem_info_folder");
            if (oemSearchType != m_fileParams.end())
            {
                oemFolderPath.assign(oemSearchType->second);
            }
            else
            {
                oemFolderPath.assign(OEM_FOLDER_DEFAULT_PATH);
            }
            std::wstring oemPathPublicKey(oemFolderPath), oemPathSessionKey(oemFolderPath), oemPathUserChoices(oemFolderPath);
            oemPathPublicKey.append(PUBLIC_KEY_File);
            oemPathSessionKey.append(SESSION_KEY_File);
            oemPathUserChoices.append(USERCHOICES_File);
            pFileReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathPublicKey.c_str(), L"File");
            pFileReader->Execute();
            pFileReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathSessionKey.c_str(), L"File");
            pFileReader->Execute();
            pFileReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathUserChoices.c_str(), L"File");
            pFileReader->Execute();

            wchar_t* ptrWStr;
            wchar_t* buffer;
            ptrWStr = wcstok_s((wchar_t*)wstrFileLocation.c_str(), L" ", &buffer);
            while (ptrWStr != NULL)
            {
                pFileReader->SetParams(ptrWStr, L"File");
                pFileReader->Execute();
                mapFileReaderResponse = pFileReader->GetResponse();
                for (std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring>::iterator it = mapFileReaderResponse.begin(); it != mapFileReaderResponse.end(); ++it)
                {
                    m_fileParams.insert({ it->first, it->second });
                }
                ptrWStr = wcstok_s(nullptr, L" ", &buffer);
            }

            if (mapFileReaderResponse.size() != 0)
            {
                m_cJobState.eFileStatus = OperationState::Success;
            }
            else
            {
                m_cJobState.eFileStatus = OperationState::Failed;
            }
        }

        if (wstrRegLocation.length() != 0)
        { 
            pFileReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)wstrRegLocation.c_str(), L"registry");
            pFileReader->Execute();
            mapFileReaderResponse = pFileReader->GetResponse();
            for (std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring>::iterator it = mapFileReaderResponse.begin(); it != mapFileReaderResponse.end(); ++it)
            {
                m_fileParams.insert({ it->first, it->second });
            }
        }
        auto emailSearchType = m_fileParams.find(L"email");
        std::wstring emailValue = emailSearchType->second;
        if (emailValue.length() > 0)
        {
            MakeCopyofEmailToHKLM(emailValue);
        }
        else
        {
        }

        delete pFileReader;     
    }

    return true;
}
```

Someone please help me by providing your review comments.

Comment: Have you profiled the code or function in a release (or full optimizations turned on) build? It may not even be slow enough to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say the code is very readable in general, although it is probably better than average.  This function is way too long and should be separated into several functions according to logic.  And the way you use the standard library facilities doesn't seem optimal.

Here are some suggestions on the code:

---

```
IOperation* pFileReader = new McFileReader();
```

**No, No, No.**  C++ is not Java.  There is no garbage collector in C++.  This line makes your code inherently exception-unsafely and error-prone.  See [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313).  The correct way is to declare a normal variable:

```
McFileReader fileReader{};
```

This avoids all sorts of problems.

---

```
if(pFileReader)
```

This is redundant because `new` never returns a null pointer.  Instead, it throws an exception that is caught by an exception handler of type `std::bad_alloc`.  Simply remove this check.

---

```
std::wstring strVendor, wstrFileLocation, wstrRegLocation;
std::wstring FileType, regType;
```

Declaring a bunch of variables at the start of a block is not advised in C++.  A reader feels puzzled when seeing these two lines.  Move these declarations to where these variables are actually used.

---

```
transform(
    strVendor.begin(), strVendor.end(),
    strVendor.begin(),
    towlower);
```

None of the arguments are guaranteed to nominate `std` in ADL, so use `std::transform` not `transform`.  Also, `towlower` can't be used like this.  Wrap it in a lambda.

---

```
strVendor.assign(manufacSearchValue->second);
```

Don't use `assign` when a simple assignment will do.  `strVender = manufacSearchValue->second` is much better.  This problem also recurs later in the code.

Similarly, use `+=` instead of `append`.

---

```
pFileReader->SetParams((wchar_t*)oemPathPublicKey.c_str(), L"File");
```

The explicit cast to `wchar_t*` indicates a *serious* design problem.  If you want to modify the string, use `&oemPathPublicKey[0]` in C++11.  If you don't want to modify the string, remove the cast.  If `SetParams` is not const-correct, correct it.

---

```
wchar_t* ptrWStr;
wchar_t* buffer;
ptrWStr = wcstok_s((wchar_t*)wstrFileLocation.c_str(), L" ", &buffer);
```

Now you are playing with pointers and `wcstok_s`.  The first thing I notice is that `wcstok_s` doesn't exist in C++ at all.  Even if it were to exist, you should be using the `string` operations.  They are usually faster than the C functions if you use them properly.

---

```
m_fileParams.insert({ it->first, it->second });
```

Shouldn't it be `insert(*it)`?  Or, if that doesn't work, `emplace(it->first, it->second)`?

---

```
auto emailSearchType = m_fileParams.find(L"email");
std::wstring emailValue = emailSearchType->second;
```

Why not `auto emailValue = emailSearchType.at(L"email");`?

---

```
else
{
}
```

This `else` clause is useless and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs
I used the dynamic allocation like as shown in the below line,                       

IOperation* pFileReader = new McFileReader();

because, 

we have written this function to read the files and loads into the map. we usually don't know what size the file has, so you can't decide how much memory to allocate until you run the program.

Comment: And also class MCFileReader is deriving from IOperation like as shown below,      
class McFileReader : public IOperation
{

public:
 void SetParams(wchar_t* wszParams, wchar_t* wszParamType);
 bool Execute();
};

Comment: Even with this point also if it is not advisable to use dynamic allocation, as per your suggestion i will use local variable like

McFileReader fileReader;

Comment: That’s irrelevant.  You always use one McFileReader, so a local variable is better.

Comment: And also about the pointer null check, I used  if(pFileReader) , because 
If new completes successfully, it always returns a pointer ( and as you said if it doesn't complete successfully, an exception is thrown, and nothing is returned).

Comment: @JohnPaulCoder That’s exactly why it should be removed.   The pointer is always non null, so the check doesn’t really do anything.